# Inline ARM Assembly functions in Emblocks or in Keil

Tags: assembly, arm, microcontroller, keil

How can I write inline ARM Assembly functions in Emblocks or in Keil for STM32F429 microcontroller?

Comment: Isn't that described in the manual for the compiler?

Comment: Thank you for your helping, I have aleady found the result in this document. Thanks!

Comment: @SzilviaLázár: Could you please share what you found? Answering your own questions is explicitly encouraged here.

Comment: asm(
    " asm instrucion ;"
    " asm instrucion ;"
   );

Answer (score 0):

This should work in [Keil](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124246903.htm):

```
// #pragma ARM  // would do the same as __arm below !
void ChangeIRQ (unsigned int NewState) __arm  {  // use ARM-mode for this function
  __asm  {
     AND    R0,R0,#0         //
     MRS    R0,CPSR          //
     ORR    R0,R0,#0x80;     //

     LDAV   R1,R10,NewState  // load parameter-value 'NewState' into R1
     BIC    R0,R0,R1,LSL #7  //
     MSR    CPSR_c, R0       //
  }
}
```

I don't know EmBlocks, but IAR and GCC allow inline istructions like asm or __asm("mov x,y") (more parameters may specify registers,inputs,outputs).

This is my code for ATSAM4L (Cortex-M4) in IAR EWARM:

```
__no_init uint reset_addr;
__no_init uint reset_reta;
__no_init uint reset_hfs;
__no_init uint reset_cfs;

extern "C" {

void HardFault(uint* stack);
__noreturn void HardFault_Handler() {
//  tst lr, #4
//  ite eq
//  mrseq r0,MSP
//  mrsne r0,PSP
    asm volatile ("MRS r0,MSP\nB HardFault"); }

void HardFault(uint* stack) {
    enum { r0, r1, r2, r3, r12, lr, pc, psr};
    reset_hfs = scb->hfs;   // fetch
    scb->hfs = reset_hfs;   // clear
    reset_cfs = scb->cfs;
    reset_addr = 0; reset_reta = 0;
    if(reset_hfs&SCB::FORCED) {
        reset_addr = stack[pc];
        reset_reta = stack[lr]; }
//  asm volatile ("BKPT 1");
    scb->softres();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work.
It recognised the registers as a simple variable and it doesn't recognise the constans for example #2.

I found in Keil: Use GCC (Project->Manage->Components,Environment,Books->Folders/Extensions)
I choose Use GCC, I give a right path and a right prefix but it does not work, I get error message: "Failed to execute arm-none-eabias'

I tryed this, because I use EmBmocks too with GCC compiler and the inline arm assembly works well there. But I need to know how I should use it in Keil.

Comment: Too bad. I was using Keil with C51 but did not use inline assembly (but `.asm` files). Try this link: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124246903.htm

Answer (score 0):

I already have given up to find a soluton for the inline assembly. I will be happy even if I found a soluton for the pure assembly *.s/*.asm I read a soluton on the Keil's page, it is not good, but I almost works weel. I have a problem with it, it does not recognise de constans like #2

Here is the example:

```
AREA     ARMex, CODE, READONLY
                                ; Name this block of code ARMex
        ENTRY                   ; Mark first instruction to execute
start
        MOV      r0, #10        ; Set up parameters
        MOV      r1, #3
        ADD      r0, r0, r1     ; r0 = r0 + r1
stop
        MOV      r0, #0x18      ; angel_SWIreason_ReportException
        LDR      r1, =0x20026   ; ADP_Stopped_ApplicationExit
        SVC      #0x123456      ; ARM semihosting (formerly SWI)
        END                     ; Mark end of file
```

(It is not an answer, but I did not write it in the comment, because I wanted to format the code well.)

Comment: `#10`? or `#0x18`? I have some old project for Keil but for C51 and it uses e.g. `#07FH`

Comment: Should work as you posted it: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124250179.htm

Comment: I get this for every each line in which #
I tried #10 #0x10
new.s(9): error: A1859E: Flag preserving form of this instruction not available

If I don't write # then thas is problem, too.